# Is there any thread-safe hash-table implementation in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable

The question stands by itself, either way, the stardard hash-table in common-lisp is not thread-safe, is there any thread-safe version implemented in a readily available package in quicklisp?

Comment: Since hash tables are a part of the CL standard and threads are not, you will have to find an implementation that offers threads but whose own hash tables are _not_ thread safe. Is there such an implementation?

Comment: @sds That is precisely my question

Comment: A non-portable solution is to use SBCL's :synchronized key-word arg to #'make-hash-table: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Hash-Table-Extensions

Comment: I only use sbcl so that is great, thanks!

Comment: LispWorks has `with-hash-table-lock`: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-144.htm#pgfId-900768 (its hash-tables are thread safe by default, but care must be taken for macros that expand to two access operations, like `incf`).

Comment: Lately, the cl-gserver actors library added a helper around hash-tables to allow thread-safety: https://mdbergmann.github.io/cl-gserver/index.html#toc-2-4-1-hash-table-agent It also maintains the order of updates and reads.